# How to get value from a MongoDB document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js

I am trying to get a value from a mongodb document, but I am not getting result even if the `request` is correct:

```
db.open(function(err, db){
var request = {
          'hash' : req.params['link']
              }

                db.collection('urlmaps', function(error, collection){
                    var result = collection.find(request, {'long_url' : 1 });
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                    res.send(JSON.stringify(result));   
                }); 
});
```

I am expecting a `var result` of type string, I am not sure of my query is enough to pull out the string from the database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use `collection.findOne(request, function(...))` instead of just `collection.find`. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. I think that you use find method incorrect. As I know, all nodejs mongodb drivers are async and use callbacks to return value.

```
db.open(function(err, db){
    var request = {
      'hash' : req.params['link']
    }

    db.collection('urlmaps', function(error, collection){
        collection.find(request, {'long_url' : 1}, function(err, result){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            res.send(JSON.stringify(result));   
        })
    }); 
});
```