# MongoDB / Node.JS: Get attribute value from document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document:

```
{
"_id":ObjectId("someID")
"email":"john@example.com"
}
```

I would like to retrieve "john@example.com" so that I can pass this value to the browser.

How do I do that?

I saw these SO posts, but I don't understand the solution at all:
[How to get string value inside a Mongodb document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033366/how-to-get-string-value-inside-a-mongodb-document?rq=1) 
[How to get value from a MongoDB document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030578/how-to-get-value-from-a-mongodb-document?rq=1)

Comment: you're missing a comma in your document.

Comment: give us some more code; how far have you gotten? Is this document already in your node.js as a variable? (Are you iterating over a mongo cursor, or are you doing a findOne?)